# Symfony: Services when using entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata

I have got a services.yml in my bundle like below.

```
parameters:
     application_stock.admin.stocklevels: Application\StockBundle\Admin\StockLevelView
#    application_stock.example.class: Application\StockBundle\Example

services:
#    application_stock.example:
#        class: %application_stock.example.class%
#        arguments: [@service_id, "plain_value", %parameter%]
     application_stock:
         class: "%application_stock.admin.stocklevels%"
         tags:
             - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: application_stock, label: stock }
         arguments: [ '', Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockLevels, ApplicationStockBundle:StockLevels ]
```

but when I am trying to change services to

```
- @security.context
- { null, Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockLevels, ApplicationStockBundle:StockLevels }
```

then it is showing me an error

```
ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\test\vendor
\sonata-project\admin-bundle\Sonata\AdminBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\
AddDependencyCallsCompilerPass.php line 48
```

Could any one please help me to solve that problem, please?

EDIT:

After adding

```
calls:
    - [setContainer, [@service_container]]
    - [setSecurityContext, [@security.context]]
```

I am getting error:

```
Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in
```

StockLevelView.php:

```
<?php
namespace Application\StockBundle\Admin;

use Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockLevels;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

use Knp\Menu\ItemInterface as MenuItemInterface;

class StockLevelView extends Admin implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

/**
 * @var ContainerInterface
 */
private $container;

private $adminId;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function setSecurityContext($securityContext)
{
    $this->adminId = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
}

...rest of code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
application_stock:
    class: "%application_stock.admin.stocklevels%"
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: application_stock, label: stock }
    arguments: [ '', Application\StockBundle\Entity\StockLevels, ApplicationStockBundle:StockLevels ]
    calls:
        - [setSecurityContext, [@security.context]]
```

And create `public function setSecurityContext($securityContext) { ... }` setter to capture security context in your admin class.

Comment: Thanks for it, but now I am getting another error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\src\Application\StockBundle\Admin\StockLevelView.php line 36

Comment: Your posted code above seems fine, so that should be another problem

Comment: I have just added code for my class and also before [setSecurityContext, [@security.context]] added [setContainer, [@service_container]] (also eddited) and I am getting Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object

Comment: You should do `function setSecurityContext($securityContext) { $this->securityContext = $securityContext; }` and only later (not in `setSecurityContext`) `$this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser()`

Answer (score 0):

You can only inject other service definitions or parameters. Not class names. You have to define you entity as another services to inject it. Maybe in the `prototype` scope.